# Why it's not enough to prevent SQL injection from front-end?

Tags: sql-injection

All most all the resources about preventing SQL injection are talking about preventing it from fron-end and back-end ,with database level. Why do we need to do all those things?

Is it not enough to do it from front end, by just preventing the user from sending malicious SQL codes as inputs.

Comment: If you can guarantee nothing is going to get through the front end it is enough.  Multi layer defense is nothing new and not limited to software.

Comment: It's all about control. There are many way of input from front-end, and you can choose to verify all the ways instead of guarding at backend at once

Answer (score 5):

Because most client-side code can be bypassed since it executes on the client's machine. Basically any code that protects against bad input on the client-side is there to provide better feedback for an honest user and also to reduce low-hanging fruit type of attacks.

The back-end code is there to make sure any malicious user who bypassed your front-end security (with a crafted http request or w/e) will not be able to inject bad input into one of your SQL dynamic query. This is usually achieved by sanitizing input on the back-end and using parameterized queries.

Comment: +1 It would be easy to use a hex editor to change the sql statement that is embedded in the executable program.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you button up your front-end doesn't guarantee SQL Injection safety. All the front end does is show pretty things to the user. The back end is where all the work is done and because the front-end must talk to the back-end in some way means you have a potential security issue.

I don't know if your application will be Winforms or a Web application, but that doesn't matter. I can use a program such as Process Explorer to manipulate the data that gets sent to your back-end, if its a Windows application.

If its a web application, then, similarly, I can use a tool such as Fiddler to manipulate the data that gets sent to your back end.

Moral of the story is always button up your back end and never let your back end assume that the data its getting from the front end is hunky dory!

Comment: So doing an back end test is enough ? without doing a front end testing ?

Comment: @prime - Doing a front end test is just responsible programming. I would do both. All I am saying is, don't let your back end assume that the data it receives is always coming from your tested front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Defense in-depth is a really, really good thing. Consider this, your app takes values as parameters to a query or perhaps even take user input to form a query. You do the right thing at the app level to correctly escape the input so injection attempts do nothing there and data is safely read or written to the database. Now, what if

1. the data that is written to the database itself is malicious code? The next stored procedure that reads from the table may now be executing random code.
2. the application code passes the "safe" data to the backend which is then used in a stored procedure or function (e.g. de-serialize, cast, etc...). Once again, you could be executing malicious code.

You could argue that instead of escaping the input, you could parse the input at the app level to strip/reject certain value, strongly type, regex everywhere, etc... but there are many situations where these restriction cannot be implemented because the app is intended to support free-flow text that may legitimately have suspicious looking characters especially if you support international character sets. (E.g. names,  descriptions, notes, etc...).

Finally, do/should/can DBAs really count on the app or app dev to get everything right every time?